# Goldfish initial pairs

Tags: java

I'm working on a gold fish game. There are four players. Whenever I try to check for initial pairs, I get a java lang exception out of bounds error. The error points to the if statement, but I don't know how to fix the code.

Here's the code:

```
public void initialPairs() {

        for (int index1 = 4; index1 >= 0; index1--) {

            for (int index = 0; index <= 3; index++) {

                if (hand.get(index1).getRank() == hand.get(index).getRank() && index != index1) 
                {
                    Card c = hand.remove(index1);
                    Card d = hand.remove(index);
                    size = size - 2;
                    System.out.println("Removed: " + c + " & " + d);
                    System.out.println("Player 1's hand:" + hand);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

A bit more info: Each hand gets 5 cards. Checking for "initial pairs" means that before people can ask if another player has their card, their hand gets checked for pairs. SO, if I have 2 Aces, it should be removed here.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do in terms of code ? I have no inclination to figure out what you have in mind.

Comment: Assuming that each hand holds cards numbered from 0 to 3, your loop over index1 starts with 4, so hand.get(index1) == hand.get(4) will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are assuming that the hand has five cards and, furthermore, you aren't adjusting the indexes after you remove a pair. Finally, when you find a pair, you want to break out of the inner loop immediately. Try this:

```
public void initialPairs() {

    for (int index1 = hand.getSize(); index1 > 0; index1--) {

        for (int index = 0; index < index1; index++) {

            if (hand.get(index1).getRank() == hand.get(index).getRank()) 
            {
                Card c = hand.remove(index1);
                Card d = hand.remove(index);
                size = size - 2;
                --index1; // adjust for removal of element at position index
                System.out.println("Removed: " + c + " & " + d);
                System.out.println("Player 1's hand:" + hand);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: When I use this code, it returns a java.lang.indexOutOfBoundsException on the line: `if (hand.get(index1).getRank() =+hand.get(index).getRank())`

Comment: @MCsuchNsuch - Hm. Perhaps the outer loop should start at `hand.getSize() - 1` (it depends on how `get()` and `getSize()` are implemented, but the code I posted is likely wrong.). If that doesn't fix it, you can try printing the sequence of values for `index` and `index1` to see what values trigger the exception.

Comment: Well, we haven't run into an error most recently *knocks on wood* so I'm gonna say you had the correct answer. Also, the error says the problem is that index1 is the same as the size. We've tried all kinds of -1 and stuff... :/ But thanks a lot for trying!!!!